# Passing double quotes into ruby script from the Linux terminal sometimes results in \" and other times in nothing being picked up in ARGV

Tags: ruby, linux, bash

I'm calling a ruby script from a bash terminal using the following line:

```
./receiveJSON.rb whatsin.json { "workers": { "Bot1": { "sentmessages": "11" } } }
```

it picks up parameters like this:

```
ARGV.each do |arg|
  if !jsonStarted && filename.empty? && arg != "{"
    filename = arg
  elsif !jsonStarted && arg == "{"
    jsonStarted=true
    contentString += arg
  elsif jsonStarted
    contentString += arg
  end
end
```

It is part of a chat bot to chat bot communication method that sends JSON through the chat (as they cannot communicate otherwise) and constructs a JSON file on the other side child value by child value.  I've run into an unexpected issue though, which I believe is caused by a version inconsistency, however I'm hoping that it's a config difference in the versions that can be changed or overridden.

In ruby 2.1.9 the content string is passed through as valid JSON:

```
{"workers":{"Bot1":{"sentmessages":"11"}}}
```

However in ruby 2.2.6 and 2.2.7 the content string is passed through as:

```
{workers:{Bot1:{sentmessages:11}}}
```

The obvious first answer is can't you use keys, rather than strings, and the answer is yes, I possibly could in this example, however that would fail if I passed something intended as string as the value, for instance here:

```
./receiveJSON.rb whatsin.json { "workers": { "Bot1": { "sendcomplete": "2017-07-03 11:57:21 UTC" } } }
```

I'm hoping someone will come back saying that I don't have to change ruby version, that it's a new ruby parameter or it's a configuration setting, since an upgrade could affect other scripts, however if that's not the case I'll just have to resort to a few minutes of nerd rage before seeing what negative affects an upgrade will bring (perhaps none).

Comment: All those quotes are gone before ruby sees the string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the quotes and curly braces are syntactical in shell see shell grammar (http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/xcu_chap02.html#tag_02_10).
to use literal must be quoted.

quoting between single quotes prevent from variable expansion, but the string can't contain single quotes even with a `\` because `\` are also literal between single quotes, a solution to insert a single quote is to close the single quote string and to append escaped quote `\'` or enclosed between double quotes `"'"` then open new single quote string.

```
./receiveJSON.rb whatsin.json '{ "workers": { "Bot1": { "sentmessages": "11" } } }'


# string with single quote
./receiveJSON.rb whatsin.json '{ "workers": { "Bot1": { "bot'\''s messages": "11" } } }'
```